# Taking the header 'setcookie' and turning it into a Cookie object

Tags: c#, cookies, http-headers

How can I turn an array of cookies into a Cookie object?

```
var client = new HttpClient(handler);
var content = await client.GetAsync("http://example.com");
var cookies = content.Headers.GetValues("Set-Cookie");
```

which I tried, but it did not work

```
var cliente = new RestClient("http://example.com");
cliente.CookieContainer = cookiesC; // CookieContainer cookiesC = new CookieContainer();
var parsedCookies = string.Join(";", cookies);
cookiesC.SetCookies(new Uri("http://example.com"), parsedCookies);
var res = cliente.Execute(new RestRequest("/", Method.GET));
```

In case I am using the httpClient just to catch the cookies and soon after moving on to restsharp. I'm looking for how to transfer cookies from httpClient to RestSharp

Comment: Which are you using? `HttpClient` or `RestClient`? Which do you want a solution for?

Comment: In case I am using the httpClient just to catch the cookies and soon after moving on to RestClient. I'm looking for how to transfer cookies from httpClient to RestClient

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare your `HttpClient` like this:

```
CookieContainer cookiesC= new CookieContainer();
HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler();
handler.CookieContainer = cookiesC;
HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler);
```

This will cause `HttpClient` to use the `cookiesC` container, which you can then use (seemingly) with `RestClient`.

Comment: im using https://github.com/elcattivo/CloudFlareUtilities like handler, so, i cant use HttpClientHandler

Comment: I just fixed it, i can use InnerHandler